# What is wrong with importing Real32 or Real64?

Tags: import, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

Those who visit the chat might have seen the [question of varkor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43173711#43173711). I'm posting it here in the hope that I have missed something.

Assume you have a real number

```
real = 57.295780181884765625;
```

This number fits exactly into a 32 bit floating point number (known as IEEE-754) as you can verify [on this site](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). However, exporting and importing it again looses information:

```
ImportString[ExportString[real, "Real32"], "Real32"] // InputForm
(* {57.295780181884766} *)
```

Additionally, you can check that the precision of `real` is about 20

```
Precision[real]
(* 19.7581 *)
```

while the re-imported number only has `MachinePrecision` which is about 15. Actually, the situation is worse because even if you use `"Real64"`, the re-imported number will still have only `MachinePrecision` and the loss of information is exactly as large as when using `"Real32"`.

I was curious if the exported bytes are wrong or if the the re-import fails. We can store the binary value and re-import it as `"Binary"` so that we get the actual bytes. These bytes are then turned into a bit pattern (the `Reverse` is due to the byte ordering):

```
bin = ExportString[real, "Real32"];
digits = Flatten[IntegerDigits[Reverse@ImportString[bin, "Binary"], 2, 8]]
(* {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1} *)
```

The bits are exactly as given on the site I linked above and we can turn them back into a number by following the [calculation of IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

```
e = Sum[digits[[9 - i]]*2^i, {i, 0, 7}];
fraction = 1 + Sum[digits[[9 + i]]*2^(-i), {i, 1, 23}];
result = 2^(e - 127)*fraction;
N[result, 30]
(* 57.2957801818847656250000000000 *)
```

As you can see, the result is exactly what we have used as input.

**Question:** Why is a `"Real32"` or a `"Real64"` not imported correctly? You will find that using `"Real128"` indeed returns the correct result and a number with an explicit precision. What is happening here?

Comment: The basic reason is that there are only two types of real numbers in Mathematica: machine precision reals (IEEE-754 doubles), and arbitrary precision reals. If the kernel could work with native IEEE-754 floats, their precision would of course be half of `MachinePrecision`. The ~20 or so precision that you are seeing is an artifact of representing the number as a bigreal. When importing, anything that fits into a native double will be converted to one. "Real128" of course, can only return a bigreal.

Comment: Well, not exactly half, but a bit less, 24/53. Also, the point of making everything that fits into a native double is so that one could have a packed array of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem.  It's a question of output-formatting, connected with the fact that there are single-precision binary fractions that cannot be represented in decimal form in 17 digits or less.

The OP notes that the input `real` has more than machine precision.
Thus it is typeset with more than `$MachinePrecision` digits. (`$MachinePrecision` is approximately 15.95).  However, the imported `"Real32"` number has machine precision, which, as the OP implies, should be sufficient for a 32-bit real,
since machine precision is double precision ([binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) and a `"Real32"` is single precision ([binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)):

```
in = First@ImportString[ExportString[real, "Real32"], "Real32"];
Precision[in]
(*  MachinePrecision  *)
```

The decimal output for `in` is rounded to 17 digits in `InputForm` so some digits appear to be lost.
The floating-point `real` is exactly equal to

```
exact = SetPrecision[real, Infinity]
(*  15019745/262144  *)
```

Converted to a machine precision number, the value of `real` is typeset in decimal `InputForm` as

```
N@real // InputForm
(*  57.295780181884766  *)
```

This is the same as the imported `"Real32"` value.  And if we examine the exact fraction for the imported `in`, we see it is the same as `real`:

```
SetPrecision[in, Infinity]
(*  15019745/262144  *)
```

It is possible that one might think that since `real` has 19+ digits of precision, outputting it in `"Real32"` form should also maintain that precision.  But I think that `"Real32"` represents single-precision.  If it were to have an arbitrary precision, the precision should be `Log10[2^24]` or about `7.22`.

Comment: +1, but it is not just a matter of output-formatting or typesetting. One number is a bigreal, and the other is a machine real, so they have a completely different internal representation.

Comment: @ilian Thanks. I realize the internal difference. I'm suggesting that the OP's conclusion that there is a problem is based on the formatting of bigreals vs machine reals. Or that's what I intended.

Comment: I see now that the binary representation of the imported number is the same. So what got lost in the export/import cycle is the information of the precision which also determines how many decimal digits are shown by Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and of course I highly appreciate the comments of @ilian.